# I can't install PodSixNet on python 3 (i get NameError)

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install PodSixNet on python 3 so i opened the command prompt and typed

```
pip install PodSixNet
```

but i get this error

```
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just download the PodSixNet sub-directory from [here](https://github.com/chr15m/PodSixNet) and copy it into your own project and then do import PodSixNet.

Answer (score 0):

`execfile` was a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#execfile) in Python 2, [removed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html). Obviously the package is intended for Python 2 only.